# How to get data from firebase with an array of indexes? React/Node.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get the data from firebase using an array of indexes as condition.

I have an array of categories and i need to get all the items with the categories from array.One item can have more categories.
I have tried something like this but foreach is not doing anything to collection. I understand that you cant pass the array to firebase so i need some other solution.

```
const getItemsByCategories = (categories: string[]) => {
  const collection = db.collection("items");

  categories.forEach(category => {
    collection.where("category", "array-contains", category);
  });

  return collection.get().then(mapQuerySnapshot);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "category" field is a list, and you're looking for **all** the documents that contain **any** of the items in another list you have in memory, then you should use an [array-contains-any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) query instead.  You can pass the array directly:

```
const collection = db.collection("items")
const query = collection.where("category", "array-contains-any", categories);
query.get().then(...)
```

Comment: I have tried that before and i get "Argument of type '"array-contains-any"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WhereFilterOp'". I see i shoud update firebase dependency but since Im new to firebase i dont know hot to update. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of the Firestore SDK.

Comment: Now i have a situation where i need to pass more than 10 ids and firebase has a limit on 10. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately and explain what the problem is.